# Word VBA - How to iterate through characters in a Table Cell

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to iterate all characters in a table cell but the performance is incredibly slow. Maybe because using Characters is expensive.

```
   For Each oRow In t.Rows

      ' Loop through each cell in the current row.
      For Each oCell In oRow.Cells

         ' If there is no background color in the cell, not worth to check
         If oCell.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdAuto Or oCell.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdWhite Then


            For i = 1 To oCell.Range.Characters.Count
                If oCell.Range.Characters(i).HighlightColorIndex = wdAuto Then
                    oCell.Range.Characters(i).HighlightColorIndex = wdPink
                End If
            Next

         End If

      Next oCell

   Next oRow
```

Is there a more effective way to iterate the Cell Range ?

Comment: Do you really need to do it character by character?

Comment: The goal is to detect portions of text which are highlighted or not,  and perform changes.  The whole cell range can have multiple formating,  and I need to inspect them individually

Comment: portions than can be single characters, or whole words for example?

Comment: they can be both, since a question mark or a exclamation would count as a single character and have a specific formating that I need to control

Comment: Most efficient might be to work directly with the WordOpenXML rather than going through the object model. Read a Range's Word.OpenXML, edit it, then write in back using Range.InsertXML. The discussion about working with Office Open XML in-place in this article should help you get started... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn423225.aspx

Comment: @CindyMeister thanks, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach was a little bit faster in my testing (about 2-3x, depending on how many characters get highlighted):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim t As Table, oRow, oCell, tm, n, rng As Range
    Dim sh, i As Long

    Set t = ThisDocument.Tables(1)

    tm = Timer
    For Each oRow In t.Rows
        For Each oCell In oRow.Cells

             sh = oCell.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex
             If sh = wdAuto Or sh = wdWhite Then

                Set rng = oCell.Range
                n = Len(rng.Text)

                rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
                For i = 1 To n
                    rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, 1
                    If rng.HighlightColorIndex = wdAuto Then
                        rng.HighlightColorIndex = wdPink
                    End If
                    rng.Move wdCharacter, 1
                Next

             End If

        Next oCell
    Next oRow
    Debug.Print Timer - tm

End Sub
```